# robocopy from remote server that requires private/public key authentication

Tags: windows, command-line, network-shares, robocopy

I know that the robocopy command will only work with existing drives, not remote servers, so if I'd like to use the robocopy command to run periodic file backups from a remote server, I have to map that to a network drive.

My script so far is something like this:

```
rem # Map the drive
net use R: \\server\path-to-file /USER:username
rem # Now use robocopy
robocopy.exe R:\ C:\local\backup\destination
rem # Disconnect the mapped drive
net use R: /delete
```

In the first line where I map the remote server to a local network drive, is there a way for me to specify a login with a private key location, rather than a password?  That's the only way I can connect to my remote server.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!  :-)

Comment: What program do you normally use to connect to the server? I'm pretty sure SMB does not support public-key auth *at all*.

Comment: Well, I typically use ssh or WinSCP to login to the remote server (which is a web server) and both of those applications allow me to login using my locally stored private key.  Public key is on the server.  I have never done this through a Windows batch file, which I think is what I need to setup a file backup script that runs nightly.  Thus my question above.  Is that what you meant when you asked how I normally connect to the server?

Comment: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/free_ssh_client_for_windows#ssh_file_transfers ?

Comment: @Boriana: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you use SFTP via WinSCP to connect to the server, and unfortunately Windows does not support that natively (you can only use SMB or WebDAV with `\\server` or with `net use`).

This also means you won't be able to use `robocopy` with it, either. (Unless you install something like [Dokan SSHFS](http://dokan-dev.net/en/), but I'm afraid that project is a bit out-of-date.)

However, if all you need to do is download a complete directory, WinSCP's [automation](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) (scripting) can do that easily, using the [`synchronize`](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize) function. Write a script similar to:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open mysession
synchronize local -mirror -delete C:\local\backup\destination /path/to/source
exit
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  I'll use WinSCP scripting.  My tests so far are working well!